# Are USB 2.0, Type-A, Male-Male cables compliant with USB specification?

Tags: usb, standard

[This was asked 3 years ago](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/444283/why-is-usb-type-a-to-usb-type-a-never-used) in a similar question but it left out some information to be desired. Are male-male, type-A-typeA usb 2.0 connectors safe, and/or compliant with current standards? Are they illegal to use in manufacturing or banned in any countries?

The last question seemed to accept that they're dangerous because they can supply power two ways, smoking things, but OK for USB 3.0 specs because they're made different.. I wanna know about 2.0

Look here's one on amazon with almost [5 stars](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00551Q3CS)

[image]

Comment: They're not illegal or banned, but they are against the USB specification and the USB-IF might get mad at you if you put USB logos on them.

Comment: I used such cable for cheap 5v breadboard power supply from china. They use USB-A as power output but it can be used as input as well. Kinda weird but its only for power.

Comment: Something being dangerous or non-compliant is absolutely no reason *not* to sell it on Amazon.

Comment: It is non-compliant, but soooo convenient for cutting in half and making cables for boards with USB pin headers :)  Cheaper than buying USB-to-bare wires.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Technically, it depends how the cable is built. In USB 2 standard these cables are not allowed at all, and USB 3 standard allows these cables only if they are build according to the standard.

They are not illegal (there is no jurisdiction with laws against them), and they are cannot be banned as they are just cables. They are just stupid, useless and non-compliant according to old specs and thus should not exist at all for any purpose, and they are only compliant according to new specs if made correctly without power supply connection.

As you might be aware, there are USB hosts and devices. To put it simplified according to old USB standards, Type A socket is used on hosts, and Type B socket is used on devices. And hosts are supposed to only be connected to devices, which is why we have cables with Type A plug on one end, and Type B plug on the other end. So you are not supposed to connect two hosts together, or two devices together, so there should be no need for cables with same type of plug on both ends.

The host is also supposed to give power to a device, so there is 5V supply available on host Type A connector, which the device can use for powering itself (e.g. sound interface) or just detect the host for presence (e.g. printer with separate power).

Now, if you have a cable with Type A plug on both ends, it allows you to do unintended things, as you can connect two hosts and their power supplies together. Two hosts cannot communicate between each other, and the power supplies are now also shorted together through the cable. If you turn off one of the hosts, the other host tries to back-feed power into the other host.

As that is not in any way an intended connection, one or both hosts may get damaged, as you are not supposed to connect power supplies together.

So this is why Type A plug to Type A plug cables should not exist, there should be no need for them. But as something always goes wrong, someone used the Type A socket incorrectly on some device instead of Type B socket, and then a Type A plug to Type A plug cable must be used to attach that device with incorrect connector to a standard PC.

Modern USB specs allow these cables to exist for debugging purposes, as some products that are usually USB hosts may be able to go into device mode for debugging purposes by connecting it to another host like a PC. But as explained above, to prevent shorting of the power supply pins together, such a cable must be manufactured so that there is no connection between the power supply pins of the connectors.

The cable should also be specially marked as being such a compliant debug cable, to distinguish them from the dangerous non-standard cables that should not exist.

Comment: Interesting and useful information about USB3 allowing them as debug tools and that in that case they *must not* have the power lines connected.

Answer (score 8):

They don't follow the USB specification. The USB 1.2 and 2.0 specify that the ends of the connectors define whether a connection is a host or a device. The male to male A connectors would be host to host, which is not supported under the USB spec.

They are typically used in cheaper devices that either use power only or the designers were too lazy or incompetent to understand that a device needs a B connection, so people still sell and use them. No entity prevents the use or sale of a nonstandard cable that I'm aware of.

Comment: One thing that somewhat mitigates is that the USB logo cannot legitimately be used on non-conforming products.  Though that does require some enforcement (it's a civil, rather than criminal, matter).

Answer (score 4):

Not only does it not comply with the USB specifications (1.x all the way up to the latest 3.x), but there is no purpose for such a cable: if one were to connect two ‘A’ hosts (upstream devices) together, they wouldn’t recognize each other. And, even worse, it ties their VBUS lines to each other, which could damage your devices if they lack back-current protection.

An actually useful cable would be to have an A plug on one end and an A socket on the other.

On the other hand, Mini type connectors allow dual-role or On-The-Go (OTG) systems to connect. They use either the fifth ‘ID’ pin to select the role at each end, or they message each other by using Session Request Protocol. More here: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/1/1822.html

Comment: "An actually useful cable would be to have an A plug on one end and an A socket on the other.". Well, these have existed since (IIRC) USB 1.x: they are USB extension cables. As for compliance with USB3, see @justme answer, it seems the latest standards allows them as debug cables, although they must not have power lines.

Comment: Are dumb "USB extension cables" now conforming?  Certainly in 1.x and 2.x they were prohibited, as they could allow the maximum cable length to be exceeded.  A conforming "extension cable" is a 1-port hub.

Comment: The purpose for such a cable would be to connect a non-conforming device, such as the one shown in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a device that would need such a cable.

[image]

We had one of these at work about 20 years ago.

And yes, it is a device, not a host.
And yes, it is non compliant, like the cable it is supplied with.

You will notice by contrast that a compliant printer has both type A and type B connectors. Type B for when it is connected to a host PC, type A for when it is hosting a camera or memory stick.

Comment: A previous engineer at my company seems to have used them to make the boards slimmer that needed USB.

Comment: @BobaJFET Would probably have made more sense to use a mini-B or micro-B, unless it was designed in the short interval between USB 1 and 1.1 (1996-1998).